# CommandButton inside dynamically rendered panelGroup fails to execute actionlistener

Tags: java, jsf

I have a very simple xhtml file where a `panelGroup` containing  a `commandButton` is added to the page on clicking toggle button but this dynamically added `commandButton` fails to execute its `actionlistener` on being clicked.

Complete code below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:panelGroup id="checkDyna">
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{listRetriever.booleanStatus}" >
                <h:form>            
                    <p:commandButton value="check" process="@all" actionListener="#{listRetriever.xx()}"/>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Toggle" actionListener="#{listRetriever.toggleBooleanStatus()}" update=":checkDyna"/>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "listRetriever")
@RequestScoped
public class ListRetriever implements Serializable {

    private boolean booleanStatus;        

    public void toggleBooleanStatus(){
        if (!booleanStatus)
            booleanStatus=true;
    }

    public void xx(){
        System.out.println("Invoked***");
    }

    public boolean isBooleanStatus() {
        return booleanStatus;
    }

    public void setBooleanStatus(boolean booleanStatus) {
        this.booleanStatus = booleanStatus;
    }

}
```

On removing  `rendered="#{listRetriever.booleanStatus}"`  actionlistener is successfully invoked.

On making the bean `ViewScoped` too the problem is eliminated but I dont want to make it wider than `RequestScoped`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this `p:commandButton` within a conditionally rendered panel whose conditional expression for rendering was evaluating to **false** while I was trying to execute the `actionlistener`. This was the cause of `actionlistener` not getting executed.

Comment: I thought that you already know that. It's obvious enough as placing the bean in the view scope solves the problem. Your sole question seemed to boil down to how to achieve it anyway without using the view scope.

Comment: yes I realised that after checking it with @viewscoped & seeing your answer at question: [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked). Thanks to you for that great answer!